# Is it possible to control the fan of a USB connected HDD enclosure?

Tags: linux-mint, external-hdd, temperature, fan

I've got a USB enclosure for five 3.5" drives, but not only is the fan very loud, it also cools idle drives down to under 30°C, which according to data floating around the Internet increases chances for drive failure.

Is it possible to turn this fan off and on? Then I could write a script to keep drives in a safe range of temperatures.

More details on the enclosure:

- 9558U3 from Orico
- USB3.0, JBOD
- IEC (power) connector

Comment: Maybe this https://github.com/desbma/hddfancontrol ?

Comment: Under prerequisites it lists that it needs a motherboard which "exposes to the OS a PWM to control fan speed" which I don't have. I need something that goes through USB, not through the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way to control the fans, but I solved the problem by replacing the fan with a different one, that is silent and doesn't cool down the HDDs inside too much.